# Drawing lines in JavaFX with FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to draw some Lines on the screen for JavaFX project. I've found documentations about how to do this with java code, but I need to do it in the FXML file. I can't find any documentation on the attributes (e.g. x and y positioning) for creating a < Line /> in FXML.

Comment: The attributes match the JavaFX properties. You just need to take a look at the section of JavaFX properties in the javadoc; All of the properties that are not readonly should ba available via the property getter name minus the `Property` suffix; For some you may not be able to use attributes though, but for primitive types, enums and strings you certainly can use attributes.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

startX, startY - starting point coordinates, endX, endY - endpoint coordinates; 
stroke - line color; strokeLineCap (BUTT, SQUARE, ROUND); strokeWidth - width line:

```
<Line startX="41.0" startY="56.0" endX="143.0" endY="56.0" 
    layoutX="67.0" layoutY="154.0" opacity="0.5" 
    stroke="#346e3c" strokeLineCap="BUTT" strokeWidth="4.0"/>
```

Lines (length = 100) indented from the beginning of the layout (x = 50, y = 50):

```
<!-- horizontal line -->
<Line layoutX="50.0" layoutY="50.0" endX="100" />
<!-- vertical line -->
<Line layoutX="50.0" layoutY="50.0" endY="100" />
```

Cursor and effect attributes:

```
<Line ...>
    <cursor>
        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        <!-- other, such as: DEFAULT, V_RESIZE, H_RESIZE, MOVE -->
    </cursor>
    <effect>
        <GaussianBlur /> 
        <!-- other, such as: Blend, Bloom, Glow, Reflection, Shadow -->
    </effect>
</Line>
```